# Encrypt file transfer from client and server

Tags: encryption, file-transfer

I am developing an application using IOS/Andriod/Angularjs for client site and Nodejs for server site.
I want encrypt file transfer between client and server for security.

Answer (score 1):

For file transfer between a client and server use HTTPS (TLS 1.2). Everything but the address portion of the URL will be encrypted.

To avoid any MITM attacks you can pin the server certificate in the client.

You can do no better security wise than using HTTPS.

Comment: I _strongly_ disagree with that last sentence, unless you know the OP and _his_ specific capabilities... HTTPs can use a crappy prime, a low key size, an invalid cert, etc; it's folly to say there is nothing better than something that _can_ be relatively weakly implemented.

Comment: OK, *strongly* suggest something better that *this* OP could potentially implement better. If the Op might use a "crappy prime, a low key size, an invalid cert, etc" what is the possibility the OP might implement another scheme more securely?

Comment: _well-done_ HTTPS is a good generic start (since it's self-validating) but it's _possible_ to do more, that's all.